# Async function doesn't execute everything in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, tweepy, discord.py

So I'm making a Discord bot using python3.7 and discord.py.
One of its functionalities is that you can send tweets from discord using the tweepy library, this is the code I have for that:

```py
@bot.command(name='tw',help='tuitea')
@commands.has_role("chechu's")
async def tweet(ctx, *, args):
    tweepy.update_status(args)
    tweet = self.client.user_timeline(id = self.client_id, count = 1)[0]
    await ctx.send('tweet sent')
```

My problem is that after the tweet is sent (this works perfectly) I want to return a message with a link to the tweet it just tweeted.
As you can see above I tried to get the last tweet with `tweet = self.client.user_timeline(id = self.client_id, count = 1)[0]` but the execution doesn't even get to `await ctx.send('tweet sent')`

I tried creating another function just to get the tweet and return a message but it isn't called so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is `user_timeline`?  Do you have any exception handling that could be preventing you from seeing errors?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that self.client_id may not be set correctly.

I played around with the code and when I substituted `id=self.client_id` with `id='59553554'` (Wendy's twitter account id) it worked fine:

> tweet = client.user_timeline(id='59553554', count = 1)[0]

I also tried using the screen_name attribute and that too returned the last tweet sent by Wendy's:

> tweet = client.user_timeline(screen_name='@Wendys', count = 1)[0]

To solve your problem, I would check to make sure that self.client_id is properly set to the existing id that the account is using, or simply plugin the screen name that you are posting with.

As far as returning a link to the tweet goes, you can build the tweet's URL by using the tweet's attributes:

> await ctx.channel.send("https://twitter.com/" + tweet.user.screen_name + "/status/" + tweet.id_str)

Here is the full code:

```
import discord
import tweepy
import os
from discord.ext import commands

prefix = "$"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(os.environ["TWITTER_API_KEY"], os.environ["TWITTER_API_SECRET"])
client = tweepy.API(auth)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def tweet(ctx):
    tweet = client.user_timeline(id='59553554', count = 1)[0]
    await ctx.channel.send("https://twitter.com/" + tweet.user.screen_name + "/status/" + tweet.id_str)
    tweet = client.user_timeline(screen_name='@Wendys', count = 1)[0]
    await ctx.channel.send("https://twitter.com/" + tweet.user.screen_name + "/status/" + tweet.id_str)
bot.run(os.environ["DISCORD_TOKEN"])
```